using aureport to determine running script and parameters
I have auditd service running on my server, and sometimes, services mysteriously go down.
I find the aureport tool helpful but I'm trying to figure out what script with parameters were executed and at what time and by who.
I tried executing it with the -x and -s switch and even with the -i switch but it only shows maybe up to 20 characters of the command.
Is there a way to expand the full command with that tool? or do I have to manually pick apart the audit.log file?
